# MeteorJS publish query not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I try to use Meteor.publish (server side) with this query:

```
return Meteor.users.find({_id:{$ne:this.userId}});
```

When I do a query on the client side with Meteor.subscribe, it works:

```
return Meteor.users.find({_id:{$ne:Meteor.userId()}});
```

so why is it not working on the server side...It seems I can only query it once its on the client side...The problem is, I do not want to download the entire collection because I will have over 20,000 users. Do publish methods not allow '$' queries?

Also how can I attach this to my following query statement:

```
return Meteor.users.find({"profile.loc":{ $near: [ to[0].profile.loc.lat, to[0].profile.loc.lon ], $maxDistance: (1/111.2)*250}});
```

Comment: Everything works as expected. If you don't want all 20000 users published on a client, you don't publish it. Read more about publish/subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer above states, you would anyway publish 19,999 users if you do what you wrote.

Your question is in 2 parts though, and you should really address both with one query: to do this you should have a publication with parameter:

```
    Meteor.publish('users', function(location) { 
         return Meteor.users.find(
                        {_id: {$ne: this.userId}, 
                          "profile.loc":{ 
                           $near: [ location.lat, location.lon ], 
                           $maxDistance: (1/111.2)*250}
                           }
                         });
```

That will screen users on the server who match the location criteria.

On the client side you subscribe to it with:

```
location = {lon: 12.123, lat: 110.2};
Meteor.subscribe('users', location);
```

or the object of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The publish method does allow $ queries. What your publication is doing is publishing all users whose id is not equal to `this.userId`. If you have 20,000 users, this method will publish data for 19,999 users.

If you only want to publish the current user's data then try:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function() { return Meteor.users.find(this.userId) };
```